# Missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a growl like jquery script I got on the web which has the following:

```
    template: function (title, message) {

        var e;

        e = [
            '<div>',
            '<div class="background">',
            '<div class="content">',
            '<h2>' + title + '</h2>',
            '<p>' + message + '</p>',
            '</div>',
            '</div>',
            '<span class="icon"></span>',
            '<span class="close"></span>',
            '</div>'
        ].join("");

        return e;
    }
```

Which is called by "this.element = $(this.options.template(title, message));" elsewhere.

I get the "Missing ] after element list" error but the list seems to be closed with a "]".

---

***UPDATE***

The proposed solutions related to the semi colon do not work. So maybe it is something else as some have stated.

I have pasted the js file on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/q6rqUa3S).

By the way, the desired effect is seen and had always been so. It is just that Firebug in FireFox and the Web Inspector in Safari and Chrome all each show four errors related to this.

Something that might be relevant is that while watching closely, I notice that the error does not come up until "self.flash("end");" on Line 86 is triggered.

Perhaps very pertinent is that the whole flash thing is a hack I added to the original code.

---

***UPDATE 2***

Thanks to the answers and comments below, particularly from "am not i am", I have moved on a bit but still need some help to cross the finish line.

If you refer to my earlier update and the pastebin, it turns out that the issue appears to have been with the "flash" function.  I have updated this as shown below:

```
flash: function (mode) {
    var self, delay, trailerDelay, interval, iterations, fadeMe;


    if (mode == "start") {
        trailerDelay = 5;
        interval = this.options.startFlashInterval;
        iterations = this.options.startFlashTimes * 2;
        delay = this.options.startFlashDelay + interval;
    } else {
        trailerDelay = this.options.endFlashDelay;
        interval = this.options.endFlashInterval;
        iterations = this.options.endFlashTimes * 2;
        delay = 5;
    }

    if (iterations < 2) {
        iterations = 2;
    }

    self = this;
    fadeMe = function () {
        self.element.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, {duration: interval})
    };

    setTimeout(fadeMe, delay);
    setTimeout(fadeMe, interval);

    for(var i = 2; i < iterations; i++) {
        setTimeout(fadeMe, interval);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {var x = 1}, trailerDelay);

},
```

However, while this gets rid of the error, I also do not get the flashing effect. BAsically, the fadeMe function has no effect. I know it gets called as using an alert there shows up. I have tried various configurations of this with the same result. Will appreciate some eyes on this.

---

**SOLVED**

Needed a separate function to handle what the setTimeout calls were doing.

```
    toggle: function (interval, delay) {
        setTimeout(function() {}, delay);
        this.element.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, {duration: interval});
    },

    flash: function (mode) {
        var delay, trailerDelay, interval, iterations, i;

        if (mode == "start") {
            trailerDelay = 5;
            interval = this.options.startFlashInterval;
            iterations = this.options.startFlashTimes * 2;
            delay = this.options.startFlashDelay + interval;
        } else {
            trailerDelay = this.options.endFlashDelay;
            interval = this.options.endFlashInterval;
            iterations = this.options.endFlashTimes * 2;
            delay = 5;
        }

        if (iterations < 2) {
            iterations = 2;
        }

        this.toggle(interval, delay);
        for(i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
            this.toggle(interval, interval);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {}, trailerDelay);

    },
```

Accepted "am not i am's" answer.

Comment: You have to show more core, since the current code is syntactically correct.

Comment: you could benefit from a js view engine to declare templates in html

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error - for example, this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KWQjA/1/) doesnt show anything wrong. This sounds like an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Syntax errors are almost always unhelpful in the "missing x", the code as given in the OP runs fine even in IE7.

Comment: @Dayo: You're passing a jQuery object instead of a function to `setTimeout`. I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8671755/1106925).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your update, and the `flash()` function that causes the error, one issue I see is that you seem to be passing a `jQuery` object to `setTimeout` instead of a function.

On lines `145-151` of your pastebin, you have...

```
setTimeout(this.element.animate(this.options.hideStyle, {duration: interval}), delay);
setTimeout(this.element.animate(this.options.showStyle, {duration: interval}), interval);

for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    setTimeout(this.element.animate(this.options.hideStyle, {duration: interval}), interval);
    setTimeout(this.element.animate(this.options.showStyle, {duration: interval}), interval);
}
```

You should be passing a `function` that invokes the animation...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    self.element.animate(self.options.hideStyle, {duration: interval});
}, delay);
setTimeout(function() {
    self.element.animate(self.options.showStyle, {duration: interval});
}, interval);

for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.element.animate(self.options.hideStyle, {duration: interval});
    }, interval);
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.element.animate(self.options.showStyle, {duration: interval});
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: I think you are on the money here. However, after applying your edit (with the "this.options.XYZ" changed to "self.options.XYZ") the error goes away but so does the flashing. I believe this is because "interval" in "{duration: interval}" is null when wrapped in a function. How can I pass the value across into the functions?

Comment: @Dayo: Yep, I missed the other `this`s. I'll take a look at the `interval`.

Comment: @Dayo: Well I don't see anything that modifies `interval` in that function, so I don't know why it would be `null`. Its value should be the same as when it was set in the `if` statement.

Comment: Wouldn't it be null because it is inside another function and thus is actually another variable even though it has the same name?

Comment: @Dayo: No, that's only if you used `var` to declare a new `interval` variable inside the inner function. With no variable declaration, an attempt to use `interval` will follow the scope chain to each outer function until it finds it. If no `interval` variable is found in any scope, you'll get a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: I have tested this using an "alert" and you are correct. Just now need to figure out why it is not working. Means something else is not right

Comment: @Dayo: Hopefully that narrows it down a bit for you. Unfortunately I won't have time to do a thorough inspection of the code. I spent a few minutes looking through, and I guess I'd probably focus on the initialization of the object. Like line 29, make sure the element has been found.

Comment: Accepted your answer as while it did not give me the 100% answer, set me on the right path to solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
template: function (title, message) {

    var e;

    e = ['<div>',
        '<div class="background">',
        '<div class="content">',
        '<h2>' + title + '</h2>',
        '<p>' + message + '</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<span class="icon"></span>',
        '<span class="close"></span>',
        '</div>'].join("");

    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to identify the source of the error in that structure.

Try

```
e = [
       '<div>'
].join("");
```

Then add lines inside the [ ] until the error is reproduced.

I suspect the cause is either title or message.

Answer (score 0):

The js engine automatically inserts a semicolon `;`. Therefore if you try the following, it should work.

```
e = ['<div>',
    '<div class="background">',
    '<div class="content">',
    '<h2>' + title + '</h2>',
    '<p>' + message + '</p>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '<span class="icon"></span>',
    '<span class="close"></span>',
    '</div>'].join("");
```

---

*In reality, semicolons are just inserted for you at **certain** newline characters.* For instance, let's consider the following simple function.

```
function myFunction()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Would return the correct value which is `5` in this case but if you modify this function as follows.

```
function myFunction()
{
    return
          5;
}
```

would return `undefine` instead of returning the value `5` (which is not the case with most other languages) because the preceding function corresponds to the following function.

```
function myFunction()
{
    return;
          5;
}
```

A `return` statement followed by a new line tells the JS interpreter that a semi colon should be inserted after that `return`. If you however, modify the function as follows, it would return the correct value which is `5`.

```
function myFunction()
{
     return(
           5);
}
```

Because here we start an expression with an open parenthesis `(`. JS knows we are in the middle of an expression when it finds the new line and is smart enough not to insert any semi colons in this case.

Comment: You should understand how semicolon insertion works - it won't just arbitrarily insert semicolons all over the place :/

Comment: Why do your examples talk about `return`? None of this seems applicable to the Array. It is very common to have a closing `]` on its own line. Unless you know of a specific browser issue, ASI isn't the cause here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
template: function (title, message) {

    var e;

    e = [
        '<div>',
        '<div class="background">',
        '<div class="content">',
        '<h2>' + title + '</h2>',
        '<p>' + message + '</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<span class="icon"></span>',
        '<span class="close"></span>',
        '</div>'
    ];

    e = e.join("");

    return e;
}
```